Fock Darwin wavefunction
The ground state of a 2D harmonic oscillator in magnetic field is a Gaussian wavepackets, and the spectrum of the Hamiltonian is solved by the Fock-Darwin states.
Are there textbooks (I want textbooks, not notes, so that I can cite them when I write the papers) that explicitly derive the wavefunction of it? It seems that most quantum mechanics textbook only talk about 2D harmonic oscillator without magnetic field.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
